# how to display a corresponding description after selecting a status in dropdownlist

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, status

I would like to ask how to display a case description when I click a status in a dropdownlist.

The status is coming from the database and is loaded into the dropdownlist.

I Already updated this from the previous version... but the problem is it returned an error like this

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\StudentCases\StudentCasesInput.php on line 112 where it is located at this area

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM casestatusfile WHERE CASESTATUSCODE = $casestatus";

 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 //$casestatuscode = $row['CASESTATUSCODE'];

  $casedesc=$row['CASEDESC'];
```

Here is my code:

```
<td>Case Code:</td>
<td>
    include ('connect.php');

    $sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM casestatusfile";
    $resultselect = mysql_query($sqlselect);

    echo "<select name = 'txtCaseStatus' id='txtCaseStatus' onChange='this.form.submit()'/>";
    echo "<option value = ''>--- Select ---</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultselect)) {
    echo "<option value = '" . $row['CASESTATUSCODE'] ."'>" . $row['CASESTATUS'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

 $casestatus = $_POST['txtCaseStatus']; 

if (!empty($casestatus)){

//$db_name="ucsaosc";


$sql ="SELECT * FROM casestatusfile WHERE CASESTATUSCODE = $casestatus";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //$casestatuscode = $row['CASESTATUSCODE'];
    $casedesc=$row['CASEDESC'];

 }
}
    ?>
```

after i click from the dropdown it will display only one static message (Case is Open) but when i click another value form the dropdown it will not change...plus the dropdown will reset back to its first option which is ---Select--- .... Pls help!?

Comment: You would have to add an event handler to check when the value of the drop down list was changed, and then things would get tricky. You would need to call another PHP page that returned the content when you passed it the code of the case, and then set the innerHTML of your output box to be that return string. Alternatively, if the case descriptions are short you could always set the 'value' in the options to the case description string, and have the js callback populate this into the body instead.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm just a newbie...i don't know how to make that into a code, I humbly ask if you could give me .... heheh

Answer (score 0):

Try this now..

If you are using `mysql_fetch_array()` it returns only the `indexed array` not `associative array`.
For that, you go for associative array like this..

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  ----
}
```

or else

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: do you have any ideas about on how to display the description after selecting a value in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Before that you mind what the values comes from resultset `$row`. You just `print_r($row);` in between the while loop.

Comment: Hey, why you are started your `<select>` at two times. just delete the `echo '<select>';` after start of php script

Comment: I already made revisions...can you give me any corrections or corrected code?

Comment: this is the error from 112 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

Comment: If you are using `mysql_fetch_array()` it returns only the `indexed array` not `associative array`.
For that, you go for associative array like this..

`while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  ----
}

or else

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   .....
}`